# Websphere: How do I deploy a DataSource along with your application?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere

I have an application developed on JBoss which contains a Datasource definition at application level. Now I'd need to deploy this application on Websphere 8.5. Is there a way to deploy a Datasource module along with your applications ?
Thanks
Max

Comment: I've never heard of doing this, so I would not be surprised if it's not possible.

Comment: The answer from @Isaac is best, though this really isn't the best idea from an administrative perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSphere supports "application-scoped resources":

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/info/iseries/ae/udat_resscope.html

You would need Rational Application Developer in order to have a nice GUI to configure those resources, though.

On RAD 8.0, right-click the EAR project, and select "Java EE" -> "Open Websphere Application Server Deployment". Should be the same for RAD 7.5 (if I recall right) and 8.5 (haven't tried RAD 8.5 yet).

Comment: You might be able to use WebSphere's AAT (Application Assembly Tool) for that, if you have no access to (or prefer not to use) Rational Application Developer.

Comment: Thank you very mich for your suggestions: I have searched a lot about "Rational Application Developer" and "application scoped resources" but I couldn't find a small example/tutorial about it. If you have any reference to an application which ships with a data source definition, I'd be very grateful. Thanks again.